# aggregation of the region's values ​in the dataset

Tags: r

```
 df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
 timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I processed the dataset.

Can we find the day of the least death in the Asian region?

the important thing here;
 is the sum of deaths of all countries in the asia region. Accordingly, it is to sort and find the day.

as output;

`date         region     death`

`2020/02/17    asia       6300 (asia region sum)`

The data in the output I created are examples. The data in the example are not real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these are cumulative cases and deaths, we need to *difference* the data.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(day = as.Date(day)) %>%
  filter(region=="Asia") %>%
  group_by(day) %>%
  summarise(deaths=sum(death)) %>%
  mutate(d=c(first(deaths),diff(deaths))) %>%
  arrange(d)

# A tibble: 107 x 3
   day        deaths     d
   <date>      <int> <int>
 1 2020-01-23     18     1 # <- this day saw only 1 death in the whole of Asia
 2 2020-01-29    133     2
 3 2020-02-21   2249     3
 4 2020-02-12   1118     5
 5 2020-01-24     26     8
 6 2020-02-23   2465    10
 7 2020-01-26     56    14
 8 2020-01-25     42    16
 9 2020-01-22     17    17
10 2020-01-27     82    26
# ... with 97 more rows
```

So the second day of records saw the least number of deaths recorded (so far).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dplyr` package for data treatment :

```
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
 timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)

df_sum <- df %>% group_by(region,day) %>% # grouping by region and day
  summarise(death=sum(death)) %>% # summing following the groups
  filter(region=="Asia",death==min(death)) # keeping only minimum of Asia
```

Then you have :

```
> df_sum
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   region [1]
  region day        death
  <fct>  <fct>      <int>
1 Asia   2020/01/22    17
```